# vim shortcut for ignore spell-checked word

Tags: spell-checking

In Gvim there is an option upon rightclicking a highlighted word to ignore all such words. What is the shortcut for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use <kbd>zG</kbd>. From `:help zG`

```
                            *zG*
zG          Like "zg" but add the word to the internal word list
            |internal-wordlist|.
```

and from `:help internal-wordlist`

```
                            *internal-wordlist*
The internal word list is used for all buffers where 'spell' is set.  It is
not stored, it is lost when you exit Vim.  It is also cleared when 'encoding'
is set.
```